# How to write python code for salary rule in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to write the python code in the Computation part of the salary rules in the payroll module.

`result = payslip.salaryrule()`

In the payslip module, I'm creating the salaryrule function like this -

```
class CustomPayslip(models.Model):
    @api.multi
    def salaryrule(self):
        hourly_rate = self.emp_amount
        return round(self.billable_hours * hourly_rate, 2)
```

But when I create a employee payslip and click on Compute Sheet button, I get this error from flectra - Wrong python code defined for salary rule.

Comment: Please provide complete error trace.

Answer (score 0):

try to add the code directly into the rule

```
hourly_rate = self.emp_amount
result = round(self.billable_hours * hourly_rate, 2)
```

and try payslip instead of self